# Ordering django many-to-many with through model

Tags: django, django-queryset

Considering Django's [example of using a "through" model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)  to specify extra data on many-to-many relationships, only changing the `Membership` model to look like

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
         ordering = ('order', )
```

such that the extra data being stored is an order parameter specifying the order of a `Person` in a `Group`.

My aim to obtain a queryset for a given `Group` which contains first all `Person` instances in the group ordered by `order`, followed by the remaining `Person` instances (not in the group) ordered by `name`.

I can do this with two querysets, like

```
# Get all beatles members ordered by the through model
qs1 = beatles.members.all().order_by('membership__order')
# Get the remaining Persons (those not in the beatles) ordered by name
qs2 = Person.objects.exclude(id__in=qs1).order_by('name')
```

These querysets do appear to contain the expected Person instances. However, I need a *combined* queryset of the two, not just a list or some itertools "chain" object, since I want to feed this to initialize a form field that requires a queryset instance.

I tried

```
result_qs = qs1 | qs2
```

but I find that `result_qs` can contain duplicates (even though I thought that the union was supposed to remove duplicates?? Why are there duplicates? This can sometimes even be the case when qs1 and qs2 don't overlap!!).

If I do

```
result_qs = (qs1 | qs2).distinct()
```

it does seem to work, but I'm dubious if what I'm doing is always going to work, and is a good way of achieving this.

Note, doing `Person.objects.all().order_by('membership__order')` results in lots of duplicate `Person` instances for each `Group` that the Person instance is a member of.

Comment: Mixing the above groups is not the same as searching just for all Persons? "Those who belong to Beatles" and "those who do not belong to Beatles"?

Comment: @raratiru could you give me an example of what you mean? I think the order of the first `qs1` would be the problem?

Comment: What I would like is the set of all Person objects ordered such that those in the Group "beatles" are ordered by their "order" field, and those that aren't in the beatles are ordered by default (name/id).

Answer (score 0):

**Update from the comments:**

As I have noted in my first comment under the question, mixing the two queries in one and partially ordering them is like asking for a "two layered" `order_by` attribute for the following query:

`Membership.objects.all()`

I am not sure that this is currently supported.

---

This is our model in an imaginary application called `Beatles`:

beatles/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}: {1} (order {2})'.format(self.group, self.person, self.order)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order', )
```

> What I would like is the set of all Person objects ordered such that
>   those in the Group "beatles" are ordered by their "order" field.

Let's prepare a memberships variable:

```
$manage.py shell

>>>from beatles.models import Membership
>>>memberships = Membership.objects.all().select_related('person', 'group')
```

Now we will manipulate the memberships variable according to our needs. Lets find all Beatles members ordered as the model `class Meta` demands:

```
>>>beatles_membership_results = memberships.filter(group__name='Beatles')
>>>beatles_membership_results
<QuerySet [<Membership: Beatles: Ringo (order 1)>, <Membership: Beatles: Paul (order 2)>]>
```

> , and those that aren't in the beatles are ordered by default
>   (name/id).

Here I get all other members and I order them by the group id. In the results you will find George two times because he belongs to two different groups.

```
>>>general_membership_results = memberships.exclude(group__name='Beatles').order_by('group__id')
>>>general_membership_results
<QuerySet [<Membership: Daring Flowers: George (order 3)>, <Membership: Misty November: Lulu (order 4)>, <Membership: Daring Flowers: Terrenton (order 5)>, <Membership: Misty November: George (order 6)>]>
```

You can order them by their name:

```
>>>general_membership_results = memberships.exclude(group__name='Beatles').order_by('person__name')
>>>general_membership_results
 <QuerySet [<Membership: Daring Flowers: George (order 3)>, <Membership: Misty November: George (order 6)>, <Membership: Misty November: Lulu (order 4)>, <Membership: Daring Flowers: Terrenton (order 5)>]>
```

Comment: I'm not looking for two single query sets. If you check my OP, I already achieved two single ones on my own (the first being members of the beatles ordered by order and the second being all Persons not in the beatles ordered by name). What I need is a single queryset which combines both of these things, with their given orders.